# Computing period, semi-major axis of binary

Tags: gravity, astronomy, orbital-motion, stars

I have mass, $g$, and luminosity of each of the stars in a binary system, extracted from a model. I calculated the individual radii from $g$ and the mass. I am trying to compute $a$, but I seem to be stuck or I'm just missing something obvious. I can't think any method that does not involve the period.

How do I get the semi-major axis?

Comment: If you *only* have mass, surface gravity, and luminosity, it's impossible to get either period or semi-major axis. Is there another datum to which you have access, that you might have overlooked?

Comment: I was afraid of that. I decided to just sample periods from kepler data. That's the best I could come up with. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To continue my discussion from my comment, what and how detailed is the model? If your model is detailed enough to include [tidal distortion](http://www.cambridge.org/resources/0521846560/7708_Tidal%20distortion.pdf) or [hotspots](http://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/science/know_l2/binary_flash.html) (the illustration is for a neutron star, but regular binary stars can exhibit hot spots too) or other interaction details, you could have enough data to determine semi-major axis using [this](http://binaries.boulder.swri.edu/papers/rew_iappp_94/) as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the specific angular momentum $h$, the eccentricity $e$, and the masses, you can determine the semi-major axis $a$.

$ a = \frac{h^2}{G(m+n)(1-e^2)} $

Of course, if you knew all those things you could also calculate the orbital period:

$ t = \frac{2\pi}{\frac{G^2(m+n)^2}{h^3}(1-e^2)^\frac{3}{2}} $